# Image slideshow with onclick on thumbnails

Tags: 7

I am theming a node. I Want the images in the node to be displayed as below:
[image]

when I click on the second image second image should be loaded , when I click on third image third image should be loaded and so on.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Simple javascript:

Below is the code in my node--contenttype.tpl.php

```
<div style = "width:500px; scrolling:no">
 <?php $listing_images = get_listing_images($node->nid);  
    if(!empty($listing_images)){
   $first_uri = get_first_image($node->nid); 
   $first_filename = end(explode("/",$first_uri));
       $first_image = str_replace("public://",             "http://localhost/drupal7/sites/default/files/",$first_uri);
 ?>
<img src="<?php echo $first_image;?>" width="500" height="375" id = "listing_main"><br/>
<?php foreach($listing_images as &$limage){
     $filename = end(explode("/",$limage));
     $image = str_replace("public://", "http://localhost/drupal7/sites/default/files/",$limage);
?>
<img src ="<?php echo $image;?>" width="59" height="44" onClick="javascript:getsrc('listing_main','<?php echo $image;?>')">
<?php
 }
 }?>
 </div>
  <?php function get_listing_images($node){
   $uri = array();
   $result = db_query("SELECT  uri FROM {file_managed} WHERE fid in (select field_listing_image_fid FROM {field_data_field_listing_image} WHERE entity_id = :entity_id) order by timestamp desc", array(':entity_id' => $node));

  while($record = $result->fetchObject()){
  $uri[] = $record->uri;
  }
   return $uri;
  }

  function get_first_image($node){
     $result = db_query("SELECT  uri FROM {file_managed} WHERE fid in (select field_listing_image_fid FROM {field_data_field_listing_image} WHERE entity_id = :entity_id) order by timestamp desc", array(':entity_id' => $node));  
     $record = $result->fetchObject();
     $uri = $record->uri;

     return $uri;
     }
     ?>
```

Below is the code in javascript file:

```
function getsrc(id,image){
  document.getElementById(id).src = image;
 }
```